# JS Regex match numbers between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I have the following code, but getting no output. When I run it here it seems to work:

https://regex101.com/r/FVkJfF/1

```
var strng = '[,][123,1][,][456,2][,][789,3][,][,][,][,][,][,][,][,]';
var rgx = \[(.[0-9,]+)\];  
var outstr = strng.match(rgx).join(',');
Write(outstr);
```

To clarify, I aim to capture all the values between the brackets if they contain a number (including the opening and closing bracket of that group)

Guess I am doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Time to learn a little more about regex in Javascript: there's a [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) function. Also, remember that `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`.

Comment: Thanks! Still no luck though :(

Comment: also remember to test your regex over on https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
/\[\d+,\d+\]/g
```

It matches a substring if it contains:

- an opening bracket
- an integer
- a comma
- another integer
- a closing bracket

… in that order, without any whitespace.

Also note that a regexp literal starts with `/`. The way you’ve defined `var rgx` in your snippet is a SyntaxError

Comment: That's not the right answer since it doesn't match `[123,123,123,12]` in `[,][123,1][,][456,2][,][789,3][,][123,123,123,12][,][,][,][,][,][,]` [regex demo](https://regexr.com/5uble)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression pattern seems to be incorrect. Javascript requires you to properly escape the square brackets when using them in a regular expression.
This should be your regex pattern:

```
const rgx = /\[(.[0-9,]+)\]/gm;
```

This can be further simplified with

```
const rgx = /\[(.[\d,\d]+)\]/gm;
```

However, you won't achieve what you're looking for with the `join` method, because `match` does not return an array but just the first match, so you can't join a single element. Take a look at the `matchAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the REGEX

```
\[(?:\d+,\d+)+\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple

```js
/\[(\d[\d,]*)]/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/uiMZnQ/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\d,]*                   any character of: digits (0-9), ',' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```

```js
const regex = /\[(\d[\d,]*)]/g;
const str = `[,][123,1][,][456,2][,][789,3][,][,][,][,][,][,][,][,]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all numbers between square brackets with at least a single comma but no consecutive comma's like `1,,2`:

```
\[\d+(?:,\d+)+]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `,` and 1+ digits
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRuQsz/1)

```js
const regex = /\[\d+(?:,\d+)+]/g;
[
  "[,][123,1][,][456,2][,][789,3][,][,][,][,][,][,][,][,]",
  "[123,1,2,34]",
  "[123,1,2]",
  "[123]",
  "[]",
  "[1,,2]",
  "[,1,2]"
].forEach(s => Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => {
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
  }
}));
```